# Build openvpn with the modified OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, openvpn

I installed openssl-1.0.2 with some logging code that added to original version by `./config shared --prefix=/usr`, `make` and `make install` commands. After that I installed openvpn according to `./configure OPENSSL_SSL_LIBS="-L/usr/ -lssl" OPENSSL_SSL_CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/" OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBS="-L/usr/ -lcrypto" OPENSSL_CRYPTO_CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/"`, `make` and `make install`.

When I make vpn tunnel, I dont see any logs in log system file. I think openvpn is using another OpenSSL. I dont know how to resolve this problem...

Comment: *`--prefix=/usr`* - this is probably a bad idea. You should put it in `/usr/local`. Otherwise, you will replace the system's version of the library. That usually leads to bad things.

Comment: What does `openvpn --version` say? What is the output of `ldd openvpn`? Also see [Build OpenVPN with specific OpenSSL version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39006247/608639). The cited question came after yours, but it has a thorough answer. It also uses `RPATHs` to ensure the expected OpenSSL library is linked at runtime.

Comment: Also see [Issue 794: Process for builing OpenVPN with OpenSSL](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/ticket/794) reported in the OpenVPN issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the libraries get installed to `/usr` and not `/usr/lib`? Because usually, the prefix is only a **prefix**, not the whole path. The argument for `-L` however is a full path, so try `-L/usr/lib`.
If that still doesn't work, try the full path with `-l`: `-l/usr/lib/libcrypto.<x>`, where `<x>` is the shared library extension of your OS, which is `.so` for Linux, `.dylib` for OS X and `.dll` for Windows.

Also, I think people would be grateful if you took a little more time formatting your question.